# Can Node.js invoke Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, node.js

Is it possible for Node.js running on a desktop to spawn a Chrome Browser window? I would like to start a Chrome Browser providing the window size and location when Node.js receives an event.

Is sys shell commands only methodology?

Comment: On what OS would you like to launch Chrome?

Comment: http://defectracker.com/2019/08/28/steps-to-execute-tests-with-chrome-browser-in-node-js/ have a look at this post with sample node.js project

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec

exec('open firefox www.google.pt' , function(err) {
if(err){ //process error
}

else{ console.log("success open")
}

})
```

This opens firefox in google page from a nodejs script, for chrome should be the same

Comment: 'open chrome' doesn't do anything on my Mac OSX 10.8.2 (with chrome installed, obviously)

Comment: on windows `exec('start chrome www.google.com', function (err) {`

Comment: Not sure how this answer was accepted... I assumed it worked on mac (surely doesn't on Windows or Linux), but comments indicate that it does not.  On what platform does this actually work?

Comment: I am not that familiar with OS X but I think the `-a` flag is necessary to open an application with the `open` command.

Comment: Not downvoting because it was the right idea but more specific would have helped. For mac OS MaxRD did the trick for me

Answer (score 20):

On MacOSX

```
var childProc = require('child_process');
childProc.exec('open -a "Google Chrome" http://your_url', callback);
//Or could be: childProc.exec('open -a firefox http://your_url', callback);
```

A bit more:

- Use "open -a" with the name of your app from /Applications and append your args
- callback function is called with the output after completion
- Link to API: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Answer (score 13):

Checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-launcher:

Launch chrome:

```
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

chromeLauncher.launch({
  startingUrl: 'https://google.com'
}).then(chrome => {
  console.log(`Chrome debugging port running on ${chrome.port}`);
});
```

Launching headless chrome:

```
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

chromeLauncher.launch({
  startingUrl: 'https://google.com',
  chromeFlags: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu']
}).then(chrome => {
  console.log(`Chrome debugging port running on ${chrome.port}`);
});
```

chrome-launcher opens a remote debugging port so you can also control browser instance using the [DevTools protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol).

[Puppeteer](http://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) is another way to launch Chrome and interact with it using high level APIs.

Comment: I did not get Chrome launching headless using localhost-url and had to add `--no-sandbox` (see: [Github-Issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/2726#issuecomment-318890564))

Comment: tanx @ebidel for interdicting Puppeteer

Answer (score 9):

With [opn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn):

```
const opn = require('opn');
opn('http://siteurl.com/', {app: ['google chrome']});
```

Comment: opn is deprecated and renamed new as 'open'

Comment: "opn" changed names to "open" https://www.npmjs.com/package/open  This is much better for my use case because it simply opens a new tab instead of creating a new instance of Chrome without a logged-in Chrome user.  This is more real-world and better for dev because it's how users actually log into your website (preserving the cache, cookies, localStorage, etc).

Answer (score 6):

I open a new firefox tab on windows here:
https://github.com/Sequoia/FTWin/blob/master/FTWin.n.js

The most salient portion:

```
var cp = require('child_process'),
    url_to_open = 'http://duckduckgo.com/';

cp.spawn('c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe', ['-new-tab', url_to_open]);
```

Note:

1. Passing the **full path** of firefox to child_process.spawn
2. Escaping of slashes
3. Passing switches/arguments to firefox.exe: passed as the second parameter of cp.spawn as an array (one entry per switch).

This call is the equivalent of typing `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-tab http://duckduckgo.com` at the windows command line.

For chrome you'd want something like `D:\Users\sequoia\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --new-tab http://duckduckgo.com/`  I'll let you work out the child_process version on your own ;)

References:

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/child_processes.html

Comment: To launch chrome browser with options in windows I tried, 
`cp.spawn('c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe' , [ '--user-data-dir','C:\chrome-path' ]` Seems 'C:\chrome-path' is considered as url in this case. Any idea to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: try `['--user-data-dir=C:\chrome-path']`? Or wrap in quotes `[ '--user-data-dir','"C:\chrome-path"' ]` or try escaping the slash `[ '--user-data-dir','C:\\chrome-path' ]`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I would think you would need to escape out to shell and then open up chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Node can only do that if you call a UNIX / Windows command, so sys shell command only.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using **open** npm package.

```
app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else open(`http://localhost:${PORT}`, { app: "google chrome" });
});
```

We can specify any browser in second parameter with open function.

Answer (score -2):

---

### This answer does not help if you need chrome stored info or chrome per se.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer
https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer

For any case that you don't explicitly need previous local stored info, I suggest using a puppeteer instance.
It comprehends all browser resources such as storages, etc