# Node.js open Chrome Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: node.js

This is a similar question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085474/can-node-js-invoke-chrome). However I am using Ubuntu and the previous question's accepted answer does not seem relevant.

I am using node to call a shell script that in turn calls chrome. A terminal opens and echo's the url but chrome browser does not open. I have also tried /usr/bin/google-chrome after discovering it from `which` command as well as `google-chrome-stable` to no avail. Why doesn't chrome launch on Ubuntu with node.js child process? Im running desktop version 16.04 LTS. If I run this shell script on the terminal without node it runs great.

JS:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
 child;

child = exec('gnome-terminal -x '+__dirname+'/ss.sh http://www.google.com',
 function (error, stdout, stderr) {
     console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
     console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
     if (error !== null) {
         console.log('exec error: ' + error);
     }
 });
```

SHELL (ss.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
google-chrome $1 --start-maximized
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Edit: I just tried running this on another box running Ubuntu 14.04 and receive the error: failed to create /home/user/.pki/nssdb directory. The plot thickens.

JAVA: If I run this with almost the same code in Java it works perfectly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String url = args[0];
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/user/ss.sh", url);
        pb.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Q: so if you type type command `gnome-terminal -x /my/directory/ss.sh http://www.google.com` it "runs great"?  Q: what happens if you run `gnome-terminal -x  pwd` (or "ls" or "echo Hello") from Node.js

Comment: Yes to Q1, it opens the shell script which opens chrome. Q2 let me try running from node... 1 min. thank you.

Comment: Yes I added the three cmds from Q2 in my ss.sh script and they all work

Comment: OK: the problem isn't node.js per se, but Chrome + your environment.  Look [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2778) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/618478/google-chrome-fails-to-start).  The problem is that your node process environment is "different" from your user shell environment.  You should be able to fix it by setting file permissions, per these links. Good luck!

Comment: @paulsm4 thank you! the answer to the second link you sent me did the trick - can you enter that as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this was file permission and it came from @paulsm4 comment. He references @A.B. answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618478/google-chrome-fails-to-start).

As soon as he posts his comment as an answer I will accept and delete this.

Comment: Cool - glad it worked!  SUGGESTION: please simply accept your own answer :)

Comment: @paulsm4 I learned this answer from you though! I feel like a plagiarist until you answer :) I just didnt want others to post an answer since you solved it in your comment.